# How to play this video in VideoView?

Tags: android, video, stream, android-videoview, playback

I want to create an application to play/stream videos, I know how to play/stream videos when I have the link but can somebody tell me how can I play this video e.g http://gorillavid.in/orophd79hi8o using VideoView or other method?? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for the job? They do it just fine.

Just remember to enable plugins:

```
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON)
```

Comment: I tried with webview but I don't want the whole page to be loaded, I just wanted for e.g when you click on a button the video should start playing/streaming in fullscreen